# Can a webpage have multiple HTML tags in the same page? what does html[2] mean in xpath?

Tags: python, html, xpath, python-requests

When I just copy the full xpath of some text by opening a specific page in chrome, it goes like:

`/html/body/div[1]/article/section/div[6]/...`

When I extracted the xpath of some text from that same page after crawling using requests.get in python, it starts with something like

`/html[2]/article/section/div[6]/...`

Can someone tell me why this happens and what `html[2]` means in xpath?

Comment: It is not entirely clear: 1) you open the page in Chrome, then copy the xpath of the element. 2) load the same page via requests.get, get the element text by xpath from the first item - and where does the second xpath come from?

Comment: I find the xpath for the same text using a function I've written with the help of lxml library.

Comment: In `html[2]` the `[2]` is the index, meaning the `html` element with index 2. I forgot if this is 0 or 1 based, so could be the 2nd or 3rd `<html>` tag, which sounds odd, as pages should have only one anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> Can a webpage have multiple HTML tags in the same page?

[`developer.mozilla.org`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html) says about `<html>` tag that

> All other elements must be descendants of this element. (...)
> **Permitted parents**     None.(...)

which does imply that it is impossible as doing something like

```
<html>
</html>
<html>
</html>
```

would break *All other elements must be descendants of this element* rule and something like

```
<html>
  <html>
  </html>
</html>
```

would break ***Permitted parents**  None* rule. That being said there exist different specification for HTML and you would need examine one you are believing it, to detect if multiple `<html>` are legal or not.